# Expand divs to fill parent element but not exceed max width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to set minimum and maximum width/height on left floated divs and have them expand to fill the parent element (body). I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this with css, and if not, maybe I could use some JS.

To imagine this effect, start resizing the window and you will notice that there will be an empty space on the right of the divs until the space is large enough for some of the divs to shift into it. What I would like to do is have all the divs expand to fill out the empty space until maximum is reached and it is time to pop in more divs there at which point the size of the divs will readjust based on how many are in the row.

In the end I want to have these divs never to be more than maximum width or less than minimum width but be self adjusting within those limits to fill entire width of the body

Here is the example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
      .imageitem {
        background-color: blue;
        margin: 0 5px 5px;
        min-width: 200px;
        min-height: 200px;
        max-width: 250px;
        max-height: 250px;
        float: left;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
    <div class="imageitem"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can interpret question several different ways. Specifics would help. `width:100%` is one simple interpretation

Comment: @charlietfl I added more detail, hope this will explain what I;m trying to do.

Comment: can't be done mathematically and keep the size constraints you want. Have to compromise on one of the width dimensions

Comment: I take that back... margins can be changed

Comment: @charlietfl can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I've been working on 2 solutions... take a look at the first  which wraps outer column elements  http://jsfiddle.net/HsAKv/8/show/ - The other uses css3 and am working on a system to use both so if browser doesn't support css3 will fallback to these wrapped columns

Comment: are you wanting left to right ordering?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I'd like left to right ordering. Thank you for taking time to create a solution. Your example is very close to what I'd like it to be. The only thing is the height should always remain proportional to width, and there should always be equal margins between the items.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by equal margins. They can't be a constant or you end up with whitespace on right, same as simple floats.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking is actually a relatively complex layout, though it's basically just responsive. Essentially you want, say, two divs that expand to fill the screen (like two cells in a table would) but once the screen reaches a certain width for a third div to move up into the row.

You won't be able to get both the dimensions you specify and to fill the screen at all possibilities, as Clark says. At 505 pixels wide, two divs will fit (2x 250, with 5 pixels gap). Three won't fit until at least 610 pixels wide (3x 200, with 2x 5 pixels gap), meaning there are 105 pixels of width where your divs won't fill the screen.

Media Queries probably are the best bet for this, but your margin will probably have to be specified as a percentage, rather than 5 pixels (unless you want to do it in jQuery or similar).

Modified from Clark's answer is this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UHqWF/2/

```
body {
    background:#edeee6;
}

.imageitem {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
         box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    max-width:250px;
    min-width:200px;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
}

    .imageitem div {
        background:#4e84a4;
        max-height:250px;
        min-height:200px;
    }

@media all and (min-width:420px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:50%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width:630px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:33.33333%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width:840px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:25%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width:1050px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:20%;
    }
}
```

However, it's jumpy, as explained above.

A better solution would be to not impose the width restrictions (and thus stop the occasional gaps to the right), such as http://jsfiddle.net/UHqWF/3/

```
body {
    background:#edeee6;
}

.imageitem {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
         box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
}

    .imageitem div {
        background:#4e84a4;
        min-height:200px;
        text-align:center;
    }

@media all and (min-width:420px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:50%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width:630px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:33.33333%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width:840px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:25%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width:1050px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:20%;
    }
}​
```

Or even have the extra space in the centre, rather than the edges, such as http://jsfiddle.net/UHqWF/4/

```
body {
    background:#edeee6;
}

.imageitem {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
         box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
}

    .imageitem div {
        background:#4e84a4;
        max-width:250px;
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:200px;
        text-align:center;
    }

@media all and (min-width:420px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:50%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width:630px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:33.33333%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width:840px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:25%;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width:1050px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:20%;
    }
}​
```

Comment: I like the box-sizing , new to me, and works great in browsers that support it. Try some of these solutions in IE < 9 and they fall apart unfortunately

Comment: a better css3 property for this is `column-count` but it does strange things in chrome, at least when I try to update it with script

Comment: This works fine in <9 with the right polyfill, which many would argue for having in all sites as standard anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I created a jQuery plugin that uses CSS3 columns in browsers that support them, and wraps elements into floated columns in browsers that don't such as IE 9 and below.

A resize maintains aspect ratio of the items. It is virtually impossible to make the transition look 100% fluid to the eye, but it is reasonably fluid looking depending on browser.

There are a few settings that can be used, they are commented.

Code to initiate is :

```
$('#container').adjustColumns({/* options*/});
```

Since part of my motivation was to increase learning curve on CSS3 useage and fallback methods I will be happy to help support this more.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SbvGJ/show/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, with a minimum width of 200px and a maximum width of 250px:

- when the screen size is between 750px and 800px, there will be a gap of up to 50px
- when the screen size is between 500px and 600px, there will be a gap of up to 100px
- when the screen size is between 250px and 400px, there will be a gap of up to 150px

Thats just how the maths of your layout works out to be.

As long as you're ok with that, perhaps you could try media queries.

So something like this:

```
.imageitem {
    background-color: blue;
    //For the sake of simplicity, i've set the margin to 0.
    //You will need to redo the maths or restructure your HTML for margins to work
    //Perhaps using an inner div with a margin
    margin: 0px;
    min-width:200px;
    min-height:200px;
    max-width:250px;
    max-height:250px;
    float:left;
}

@media all and (max-width:250px) and (min-width:200px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:100%;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width:500px) and (min-width:400px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:50%;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width:750px) and (min-width:600px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:33%;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width:999px) and (min-width:800px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:25%;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width:1249px) and (min-width:1000px) {
    .imageitem {
        width:20%;
    }
}
```

If you need the height to resize as well, you could write a similar query for min-height and max-height. Just make sure you set the height on the `html, body` selector as well.